# General rule of thumb for margins

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

Is there a general rule of thumb for figuring out what margins should be based on paper size? I am starting a project that is 8" x 8" square, all text.

Comment: No. There is not.

Answer (score 3):

There's not a general rule of thumb for anything... If it was that easy, design would have been automated already.

Do some test prints while designing to figure out what works for your project.

My only advice would be to keep it equal as much as possible, at least for things that belong together or are the same.

Comment: Thank you too! I wasn't looking for a template to copy. Maybe my use of 'rule of thumb' was misleading. But as mentioned above, there are often general ratios that many people find pleasing to the eye and I thought there might be one here, how much white space vis-a-vis text, that I could use as a starting point.

Comment: "There's not a general rule of thumb for anything" of course there is, that's what a rule of thumb is ;)

Comment: @Cai I meant for anything margin related, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are really no rules.

However, it's generally best to keep all *critical* content at least 1p6 picas or .25" from the trim edge. This ensures nothing gets too close to an edge if it's imperative that it's seen. Stock/paper can shift a little running through a press. (minimally use 1 pica or .125" - I personally prefer 1p6)

Each piece is unique, so this is **not** a "rule" by any means. It all depends upon your design.

Of course, if you want something to bleed, then ignore that and go the other direction 1p6 or .25" outside the trim edge.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes there are general ratios that are pleasing to the eye. I thought there might be one for this I could use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're searching is rules for making layout with grids. For a good start, study the classic book, "Grid systems" by Josef Müller-Brockmann.

Beside bleed & safe area as explained by Scott, Josef suggested to leave enough area so that the thumb doesn't obscure the text when holding up the printed material. But that's also a general rule, it's a case-by-case basis.

A book spread layout works differently compared to an ad poster compared to an invitation card.